# Datatables param 0 row 0 column 0 error

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

My issue is datables error for parameter 0 row 0 column 0 datables.net/tn/4.  I'm using ajax to retrieve my data and populate the table.

here is the ajax

```
        $.ajax({
        url: 'DAL/WebService1.asmx/FabGuide',
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#datatable").dataTable({
                data: data,
                columns: [
                    { 'data:': 'accountCode' },
                    { 'data:': 'accountValue' },
                    { 'data:': 'description' },
                    { 'data:': 'manufacturer' },
                ]
            });
        }
    });
```

Here is the table

```
                        <table id="datatable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>accountCode</th>
                                    <th>accountValue</th>
                                    <th>description</th>
                                    <th>manufacturer</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
```

Here is what my array looks like
[image]

Maybe I have just been looking at it to long
Thanks

Comment: You have extra comma after `{ 'data:': 'manufacturer' },//<-- remove comma` . Might this be the issue?

Comment: nope i thought that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'DAL/WebService1.asmx/FabGuide',
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var arrData = [];
        data.forEach(function(item){
            var aux = [];
          aux.push(item.accountCode);
          aux.push(item.accountValue);
          aux.push(item.description);
          aux.push(item.manufacturer);
          arrData.push(aux);
        });
        $("#datatable").dataTable({
            data: arrData,
            columns: [
                { title: 'accountCode' },
                { title: 'accountValue' },
                { title: 'description' },
                { title: 'manufacturer' },
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

The `data` attribute receive an array of array elements; check the documents: https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo in your initialization code - there is no option `data:`, it should be `data` instead.

Correct code is shown below:

```js
// ... skipped ...

$("#datatable").dataTable({
   data: data,
   columns: [
      { 'data': 'accountCode' },
      { 'data': 'accountValue' },
      { 'data': 'description' },
      { 'data': 'manufacturer' }
   ]
});

// ... skipped ...
```

Comment: ??? I guess you really meant `dataSrc : ''`, that would be the correct answer. The accepted answer, pushing all the data to another array is just llame :)

Comment: @davidkonrad, not really, `dataSrc: ''` is not needed since OP uses JavaScript object as data source.